# Magento Accessing sku's by order id on success.phtml

Tags: php, magento

On the success.phtml template, I need to list the sku's from the completed order.  How can I iterate through the order and retrieve these values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should extend Mage_Checkout_Block_Success

and add the method similar to this:

```
 public function getOrder()
    {
        return Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getLastOrderId());
    }
```

and in your success.phtml template:

```
$order = $this->getOrder(); 
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
//$item is your product object and you can do what you want with this;
}
```